# regex in postgres 8.4

Tags: sql, regex, database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to write this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT createdcfgid FROM ab WHERE (createdcfgid ~ ‘^[0-9]+$’)
```

This results in

```
 syntax error at or near "[" LINE 3: WHERE (createdcfgid ~ ‘^[0-9]+$’)
```

Anyone there who can give me a clue about what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does just look like you are using the wrong quotes, try `'` rather than `‘`:

**PostgreSQL 8.4 Schema Setup**:

```
create table ab(createdcfgid text);
insert into ab(createdcfgid) values ('111');
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT createdcfgid FROM ab WHERE (createdcfgid ~ '^[0-9]+$')
```

**Results**:

```
| CREATEDCFGID |
----------------
|          111 |
```

*this on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/95357/1)*